# Draw circle with an EllipsePolygon in ImageSharp

Tags: imagesharp

I've just started using ImageSharp to draw images. The documentation on Six Labors web page is clean, but there is no examples to find anywhere about ImageSharp. So I struggle from time to time, all by myself :)

I want to draw a circle with PathBuilder and a given position in x and y as a center point, and a given radius.

I tried to use an EllipsePolygon where you can define x, y, and radius. And then I wanted to draw it in my PathBuilder but PathBuilder only has "AddEllipticalArc" what I can find.

So I have used this function to draw circles instead, like this for example:

```
pb.AddEllipticalArc(new Point(300, 200), 10, 10, 0, 0, 360);
```

Is there a better way to draw circles? Or am I supposed to use AddEllipticalArc?

---

Bonus question: I also have to draw Arcs with only a centerPoint, startPoint and endPoint given to me. But I guess I have to translate these given points and calculate the startAngle and sweepAngle myself. What could be the easiest alternative for this?

Comment: Latest builds don't use that syntax anymore. We follow SVG approach.


https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp.Drawing/blob/0d738da9a9b471e38170c79d635161bf4171fd0b/src/ImageSharp.Drawing/Shapes/PathBuilder.cs#L251

Comment: I don't really understand, could you lead me through how I'm supposed to use it, drawing an Arc for example? I followed your link and read about drawing an elliptical arc to the current figure using startPoint and endPoint. Also not using "AddElipticalArc" but seems to use AddArc or AddSegment? I don't really understand.
Thank you for your response!